# How to run a shell command in a specific folder

Tags: go

I can use this `out, err := exec.Command("git", "log").Output()` to get an output of the command which will run in the same path as the executable  location.

How do I specify in which folder I want to run the command?

Comment: Have you tried `os.Chdir`? https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir

Answer (score 142, accepted):

[`exec.Command()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) returns you a value of type [`*exec.Cmd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd). `Cmd` is a struct and has a [`Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Dir) field:

```
// Dir specifies the working directory of the command.
// If Dir is the empty string, Run runs the command in the
// calling process's current directory.
Dir string
```

So simply set it before calling `Cmd.Output()`:

```
cmd:= exec.Command("git", "log")
cmd.Dir = "your/intended/working/directory"
out, err := cmd.Output()
```

Also note that this is specific to `git` command; `git` allows you to pass the path using the `-C` flag, so you may also do what you want like this:

```
out, err := exec.Command("git", "-C", "your/intended/working/directory", "log").
    Output()
```

Comment: Nice point about git. Thanks!